# Поиск сотрудников по отделениям

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня есть несколько сотрудников, причем один из сотрудников работает в Главном отделении, а другой сотрудник работает в подчиняющемся Главному отделении. Я пытаюсь написать запрос, который выводил бы всех сотрудников, которые работают в Главном подразделении и подчиняющихся ему отделениях. Однако у меня в результате выводятся только сотрудник Главного отделения. Вот пример работы запроса: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f7eb/2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как его можно исправить?

Comment: А какой может быть уровень вложенности подразделений ? судя по схеме тут нужен рекурсивный запрос, потому что уровень вложенности не ограничен. И вы не сказали в каком виде вывести

Comment: Уровень  вложенности подразделений такой: может быть много Главных подразделений у которых может быть много подчиняющихся. Причем  подчиняющиеся подразделения являются уникальными. Выводить должно следующее ID сотрудника, ФИО, 
Главное подразделение, и, если сотрудник работает в подчиняющемся, то вывести и название этого отделения.

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос, каков уровень вложенности, т.е. может ли у подчиненного подразделения быть свое подчиненное, а у того еще одно подчиненное. И что тогда выводить в наименовании подразделений, путь ? ("Главное/Подчиненное главного/Подчиненное подчиненного")

Comment: Может быть только так (Главное/Подчиненное главного) (Главное2/Подчиненное главного2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос и уровень вложенности один (что вытекает из того, что вы пытаетесь использовать обычный join, а не рекурсивный запрос), то так:

```
SELECT e.ID, s.DeptName, ss.DeptName, e.FullName
  FROM StructuralSubdivision AS s
  JOIN StructuralSubdivision AS ss
    ON s.DeptKod IN (ss.PKod, ss.DeptKod)
  JOIN ListPositionSubdivision AS ls
    ON ls.NameSubdivision=ss.DeptKod
  JOIN Employees AS e
    ON e.ID = ls.IDEmployees
  JOIN Position AS p ON ls.NamePosition = p.ID
 WHERE s.DeptName = 'Главное подразделение'
   AND p.Name = 'Доцент'
```

А если не так, то опишите нормально структуру, с такими названиями полей понять ничего не возможно вообще, почему например поля явно содержащие ID называются Name ?

Comment: Да, все работает правильно только как можно сделать так что если SubDept = MainDept то SubDept  = NULL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f7eb/26

Comment: @SergeyZavada http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f7eb/31

Comment: А теперь вопрос в другом если из условия убрать AND s.DeptName = 'Главное подразделение' то запрос выводит следующее http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f7eb/39 и GROUP BY не помогает, как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: @SergeyZavada s.PKod is null

Comment: Спасибо, большое)